# "ant clean all" command breaks acceleratorservices platform

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm doing the process of upgrading a project from version 5.4 to 2105.

When '`ant clean all`' command is executed, the environment is broken.

[image]

Any suggestions on how I can solve this problem?

I believe it is something that is overwriting the spring version lib

Comment: Hi Please check which version of the jar is present inside the platform/springintegrationlibs/lib/spring-integration-ftp-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar

Comment: @RaushanKumar the lib is : spring-integration-ftp-5.4.7.jar

Comment: can you please check if you have more then one class reference of this class DefaultFtpSessionFactory, that might create conflict state during build.

Comment: @RaushanKumar these are the classes that conflict during the build: DefaultUploadTransportService,
ConfigurableSessionFactory